# Whats causing a Download file size limit?

Tags: php, download, php-ini

We have lots of files on site available for download, however any file above 30mb downloads as a 0kb file. Anything under 30mb downloads fully.

Anyone know if there's a setting in php.ini i need to change in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: How do you send the file’s contents?

Comment: show some code on your download mechanism

Comment: Indeed - are you simply linking directly to the file and letting the browser determine what to do with it, or are you reading the file contents and outputting it via PHP code?  There's a pretty big difference in the two approaches.

Comment: We need to see the download mechanism, or any answer is simply a _guess_, which isn't really appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you can edit your question to include the code that actually sends the file, please flag this for moderator attention to be re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

the property you are looking for is most probably `memory_limit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link: http://www.softdwn.com/how-to-increase-the-limit-of-memory-php-and-file-download-and-script-execution-time-limit/

> *2 Download file size limit value*.
>   It provides some clarifications about configuring PHP file download limit, either in `php.ini` file or `.htaccess`.